# SQL query - how do I restrict to the rows I'm interested in

Tags: sql, t-sql, inner-join

I have the following tables - simplified quite a bit

```
Table - Tests
Test
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H

Table - TestHistory
Test    Result    Version
A       Pass      1
A       Fail      2
B       Pass      2
C       Fail      1
C       Pass      2
D       Fail      1
D       Fail      2
E       Fail      1
```

I want to get the list of tests that failed (or any status) the *last time they ran*.  But, also the version that it was found in.

So, in the above example, I want this returned:

```
A    Fail    2
D    Fail    2
E    Fail    1
```

I've tried a couple methods

```
select Test, LastResult = IsNull((Select Top 1 Result From TestHistory Where Test = Tests.Test order by Version desc), 'NOT_RUN')
from Tests
```

What this does, is gives me a list of all tests and then I have to go through and kick out the rows I don't want (i.e. isn't Fail).  This also doesn't give me the Version it ran in.

I also tried this:

```
select Version, TH.Test, Result
from TestHistory as TH inner join Tests as T on TH.Test = T.Test
where Result = 'Fail'
```

But, then I get rows such as:

```
Test    Result    Version
C       Fail      1
```

I don't want those because it's not the *Last Result*.

How can I restrict this to give me exactly what I need without a lot of data manipulation (or worse, more DB reads) after?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why test `A` has the first version `Pass` and the second version `Fail` ? Shouln't be first `Fail` and then `Pass` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - no, because, I could have run test A on version 1 and it passed and ran it on version 2 and it failed.  version 1, 2, ..., x are different versions of software, for example...but doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't syntax check this, but it should be close:

```
SELECT
  th.Test,
  th.Result,
  th.Version
FROM
  TestHistory th
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
      MAX(Version) as MaxVersion,
      Test
    FROM
      TestHistory
    GROUP BY
      Test
    ) sub ON sub.MaxVersion = th.Version AND sub.Test = th.Test
    WHERE 
      th.result = 'Fail'
```

Explanation: First, in the subquery, you get the maximum version for the test.  Then use a join to restrict the outer query to only return the results that match the test/version of the subquery.

Edit: forgot the WHERE clause--seems you only want rows where the most recent result is failure.

**Edit based on the question in your comment:**

This should give you the most recent failure, plus tests that have never run.  Note that this will filter out tests that *have* run but have never failed (your data does not have any of these).  I based this on my original query in the interest of time, but I would guess there is a more elegant way:

```
SELECT
  t.Test,
  outerSub.Result,
  outerSub.Version  
FROM
  Test t
  LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
  th.Test,
  th.Result,
  th.Version
FROM
  TestHistory th
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
      MAX(Version) as MaxVersion,
      Test
    FROM
      TestHistory
    GROUP BY
      Test
    ) sub ON sub.MaxVersion = th.Version AND sub.Test = th.Test
) outerSub on outerSub.Test = t.Test
    WHERE 
      outerSub.result = 'Fail' OR outerSub.Test IS NULL
```

Comment: yes...thanks, Phil.  I just added another inner join to get the rest of the information I needed from the test table and bam...it worked.  All the answers actually worked but this one was more straight-forward to me and easier to implement using the data query object I had.  thanks!

Comment: one more question, Phil, if you don't mind?  If I also wanted to get the tests that HAVE NOT run, how would I modify this?  (So, similar to where I was also selecting those in my query above).

Comment: yes...perfect!  Thanks, Phil...I appreciate that very much.  That worked exactly as I needed.  If I could give you a 20 up-vote, I would.

Answer (score 2):

Small correction can be added to the above solution.
In case when You need to receive the results in the Test order, the query can be transformed as below:

```
SELECT src.Test, src.Result, src.Version
FROM
(
    SELECT th.Version, th.Test, th.Result, 
         ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by th.Test order by th.Version desc) as RowNum
    FROM dbo.TestHistory as th
) src
WHERE src.RowNum = 1 and src.Result = 'Fail'
order by src.Test;
```

Among this, the query will return the set in the needed columns' order.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select th.* from testHistory th 
where th.result = 'fail' -- this part, according to you, being optional
and th.version = 
    (select max(t.version) from testhistory t 
     where t.test = th.test);
```